# using $.deferred as publisher / subscriber?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Since `$.Deferred();` object can be resolved and many can subscribe the `done/always/fail` methods-

I thought to myself : "well I can use it as  publisher /  subscriber ..."

So I made a simple test ([**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/ObeGuxi/1/edit)) :

I have 3 checkboxes :

[image]

And I want to display alert when all 3 are checked :

```
var t =  $.Deferred();


$(":checkbox").on('click',function (){
    t.resolve("blabla");
});


t.done(function (val)
{
  if($(":checkbox:checked").length==3) alert('ok');
});
```

But the `done` callback is only resolved once.

Is there anything I can do so this code will function as subscriber/publisher ?

**NB**
*I know that there are many other alternatives to `deferred`. But my question is specifically about `deferred`( which can / can't use as pub/sub).*

Comment: You are better off using jQuery.callbacks for pub-sub. jQuery.callbacks are used internally to manage Deferred callback queues, but we are also allowed direct access to them. There's a great little pub-sub example tucked into the [$.callbacks API page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I  got to ask  : I could simply use  function which executes each click and check the condition. so what do I gain by  using deferred/callbacks vs calling single function which evaluates the condition... ? ( except the fact that I can chain future callbacks to an unresolved object yet)

Comment: As is says in the article, "the general idea behind pub/sub (Publish/Subscribe, or, the Observer pattern) is the promotion of loose coupling in applications". In other words, you've got publishing code and subscribing code but the one doesn't call the other as such. They are linked, in this case, via the concept of "notification".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Deferred object is resolved, its state is considered finalized. But you're right, there's a pubsub mechanism, called Deferred.progress. It's usually employed when Deferred object's state changes gradually, so these gradual changes should be tracked as well.

You can use [**Deferred.progress**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) for subscribing, and [**Deferred.notify**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notify/) (or [**Deferred.notifyWith**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.notifyWith/), if you want to switch the callback's context) for publishing. Your code, in particular, might be written like this:

```
var t =  $.Deferred();
t.progress(function(val) {
  if($(":checkbox:checked").length == 3) alert(val);
});

$(":checkbox").on('click',function (){
    t.notify("blabla");
});
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AFpSv/).